# Flexible iFrame size after page load

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, recaptcha

I have a reCaptcha in an iframe on my page. The reCaptcha changes it size, but the iframe not. I saw a few topics that address this problem. They work if the content stays the same during page load. But they do not work if the content changes when the page is loaded, this is happening in my case.

So my question is: how do I make an iFrame adjust size when the page is loaded if the iframe changed size using only html, css and if needed javascript . This is my html code:

```
 <div>
  <iframe aura:id="vfFrame" src="/partners/B2B_ReCaptcha"  frameborder="0" 
   width="100%" allowtransparency="true"  />
</div>
```

Any tips on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Did you try media queries for controlling the size of element against resolution of the screen?

Comment: No I am not familiar with those, how would that work?

Comment: You will define (by Css) the size of a specific element in order to the size of the device which the user is using.

Comment: @EliasMP The promlem is not the size of the device, rather it is the various size of the document loaded into a fixed size iframe.

Comment: Mmmm... I think I get you now. What about to set a width and height to the parent div? This way, the container div will have the same size all time...

Comment: It is a kind of race condition you've at hands. The iframe has a fixed size, which partially also defines the size of the loaded document. You have to wait until all the content will be loaded (DOM ready is not enough), then get the size of the content, and adjust the size of the iframe accordingly. However, getting the size of the content has some cross-browser issues, and it also depends on the layout, (off-flow elements!) and also on the overflow styling, i.e. scrolling arrangements on pages. All these in mind you've to build your own resizing algorithm, there's no generic solution.

Comment: All that said, you can't access a third-party page within the iframe to get the size information, hence the only chance is to fix the iframe size big enough to fit all sizes of the captchas.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu, I will build my own solution